# Where does our current technology fit into the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, history

In the movies and comic books, you see lightsabers, faster-than-light travel, planet sized lasers, Galactic empires, and much more.

This must mean that the Star Wars universe has gone through the same technological advances as us in the modern day.

So the question is, when did it happen? When did the Star Wars universe, say, discover fire, or use nuclear power like us right now?

Comment: A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away...

Comment: A long time ago? So this is before modern time??

Comment: @user12511623 Every movie starts with those words.

Answer (score 1):

[image: A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away....]

Once upon a time in a country far, far from here, there was a farm boy who met an old wizard in the desert. The wizard gave him his father's old magic sword and sent him on a quest to rescue a princess from an evil sourcerer in a flying castle.

That opening crawl isn't accidental. The wording is to tell you that Star Wars isn't sci-fi, it's fantasy. It's a tale of magic swords and wizards and flying castles. The actual technology and whether any of it is meaningful or viable is not up for consideration. This is a fairy tale about rescuing princesses from evil wizards.

Comment: Makes sense. It's sci-fi, not reality. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Or rather, it's fantasy.

Comment: @user12511623, it's an important distinction, hard sci-fi has to justify everything, soft sci-fi has to consider it, fantasy justifies nothing.

Comment: That's an excellent comment! Highly quoteable! Thanks!